# Pivoting a multi-index table where the number of columns is not static

Tags: python, pandas

This seems to have me stumped.

I'm essentially trying to get from this:
[image: img]

To this:
[image: img2]

In the first picture, the `shop` and `shop_name` columns have the same values each time if the shop is the same. Only the `customer` and `month_of_purchase` columns can change.

We see that in the 2nd picture, the number of rows has been reduced to reflect the number of shops. So each unique shop is just one row. And every customer who makes a purchase from that shop gets their name and month of purchase added on as a *column*.

But because there isn't a defined limit on the number of customers any shop can have, the number of columns can therefore get indefinitely large.

I'm unsure as to how to go about making the needed pivots.

This is some example code needed to generate the dataframe from the first pic:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"shop":['a','a','a','b'],
                   "shop_name":['best_shop',"best_shop","best_shop","good_shop"],
                   "customer":['customer_1','customer_2','customer_3','customer_4'],
                   "month_of_purchase":['Jul','Jul','Aug','Aug']})
```

I know that the next step is just to set the index appropriately, but how to do the necessary pivot after that is something I can't put my finger on:

```
df2.set_index(['shop','shop_name'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), sorting second level of `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), rename column, replace missing values and last flatten MultiIndex:

```
g = df2.groupby(['shop','shop_name']).cumcount().add(1)

df = (df2.set_index(['shop','shop_name', g])
          .unstack()
          .sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)
          .rename(columns={'customer':'name'})
          .fillna(''))

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'customer_{x[1]}_{x[0]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  shop  shop_name customer_1_name customer_1_month_of_purchase  \
0    a  best_shop      customer_1                          Jul   
1    b  good_shop      customer_4                          Aug   

  customer_2_name customer_2_month_of_purchase customer_3_name  \
0      customer_2                          Jul      customer_3   
1                                                                

  customer_3_month_of_purchase  
0                          Aug
```